# Does 'in 20 years' indicates time in the past or future

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense, time

> ABC city sees a doubling of air pollution in 20 years.

does this 'in 20 years' mean the past 20 years or the next 20 years to come?
I have found a similar structure in [news](https://www.newindianexpress.com/states/karnataka/2020/jul/23/with-covid-surge-karnataka-sees-cases-doubling-in-10-days-2173495.html) titles, see quoted:

> With Covid surge, Karnataka sees cases doubling in 10 days

It seems the indicated time refers to the past. But 'in' can also mean time in the future right?

Comment: The expression is ambiguous, and the context should resolve this.

Comment: It could be either, unless time reference is given. Covid, now, is a past and a likely future problem as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does "in 20 years" indicates time in the past or future?

No.   It's a prepositional phrase.   It doesn't have a verb, and it doesn't have any tense.   On its own, it doesn't indicate *anything* about the past, the present, or the future.

> With Covid surge, Karnataka sees cases doubling in 10 days.

The only finite verb here is "sees", which is a present-tense construction.   This headline expresses the current state of a trend.   The participle "doubling" (even though it's traditionally called a *present participle*) does not have any tense, and so the complete phrase "doubling in 10 days" is also a tense-free constituent.   It is natural to assume that *doubling in 10 days* has happened in the recent past and will continue in the near future.

> ABC city sees a doubling of air pollution in 20 years.

This example uses similar grammar: a phrase with no tense inside a present-tense clause.   Here, the "doubling of air pollution in 20 years" is a *gerund* phase acting as the direct object.

This might not be the same sense of the verb *to see*.   In the earlier example, *to see* probably means something like *to experience* or *to observe*.   In this example, *to see* probably means something like *to forecast* or *to anticipate*.

One difference is that we've gone from days to years.   Another is that the *doubling* is itself the direct object here, although "cases" is the object in the first example.   Pragmatically, the *forecasting* interpretation is more likely -- although additional context could easily change that.

The tense of the verb, the meaning of the verb, and the way that the constituent in question attaches to the verb all influence how (and even whether) we place that constituent in time.   The object of a present-tense observation makes sense in the present, and the object of a present-tense forecast makes sense in the future.

A prepositional phrase, and even a participial phrase, has no tense.   Such phrases can be used in clauses with any tense.   What matters is how it relates to a constituent that does have tense.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, "in 20 years" is itself ambiguous. But in your first example, I think the question hinges on the meaning of "sees". The use in the first example is synonymous with "foresees", "expects" or "predicts", and applies to the future.

[Lexico "see"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/see)
"2.3 Foresee; view or predict as a possibility."

The linked article, however, refers to neither the past nor the future, but to the "doubling rate" of covid. That means that for every ten-day period, its prevalence doubles. That must be based on experience (past), but would also apply to the future, unless something changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think "In 20 years" means "20 years from now" at least-that's how I see it. For the past, it would be "20 years ago", so my answer is the future.